# If $G$ Is Finite Cyclic Group Then There Is $h=\min\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^k=e\}$

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> let $G$ be a finite cyclic group
>
> Prove:  there is s.t $h=min\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^k=e\}$

Because $G$ is finite there are $0\leq i <j \leq n$ s.t $i\neq j$ and $g^{i}=g^{j}$ therefore wlog $e=g^{j-i}=g^k$

wlog let assume there are $q<s$ s.t $g^{q}=g^{s}=e\iff g^{q}=g^{q+m}=g^{q}g^{m}=e$ now if $q<m$ we are done, else we continue with $m$ until we will find $h=\min\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^k=e\}$ there we will be one because $G$ is finite.

Are the claims correct? is the proof vaild?

Comment: A bit too complicated.  You just have to show that $\{k\in\mathbb N\mid g^k=e\}$ is non-empty; pigeonhole might help.  Draw your conclusion since every non-empty set of the naturals has a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The middle part of your proof is redundant. You showed that because $G$ is finite there are $i<j$ such that $g^{i}=g^{j}$, or $g^{j-i}=e$. In other words

$$\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^{k}=e\}\neq\emptyset$$

So you now have a non-empty subset of integers, thus $h\equiv\min\{k\in\mathbb{N}:g^{k}=e\}$ always exists.

Comment: This is essentially my comment ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Took time to write... You got me early by 2 minutes.